# Android Webview - navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition not working

Tags: android, geolocation, android-webview

I have a very, very simple scenario and I am running into a very common issue (noted by many StackOverflow users over time).  However, I have tried every proposed solution, and none of them seem to work.  Can somebody please help to resolve this question once and for all?

I am building an Android app (for Android 7, let's assume) which contains a Webview which points to a website that implements very simple geolocation.  (My latest, very stripped down version of the website simply displays the user's latitude and longitude.)

I can view the site fine (and it displays latitude/logitude perfectly) in Chrome.  But when I run the app using Webview, nothing is displayed.

Over the past few days, I have tried seemingly every proposed solution (in MainActivity.java) to this issue, but none of the solutions seem to work.

I have added all permissions imaginable in AndroidManifest.xml.

What does one need to do to get this to work?

Surely, viewing a website with geolocation in an Android app with Webview should be fairly straightforward, right???

**Edit:**  I've narrowed things down a bit.  I've prompted the user for permissions at runtime, and I've confirmed that geolocation is being allowed.  I've also confirmed that Javascript, in general, is being allowed by my app.

The key/core remaining issue seems to be this:
The following does **not** appear to work in Webview.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
```

I don't know why, but that is the problem.

Ref:

[Android webview error when asking for geolocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49920241/android-webview-error-when-asking-for-geolocation)

[The application does not have sufficient geolocation permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39064165/the-application-does-not-have-sufficient-geolocation-permissions)

[Location is accessed in Chrome, doesn't work in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34986413/location-is-accessed-in-chrome-doesnt-work-in-webview)

[Android Ask for permission to use location within webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23498523/android-ask-for-permission-to-use-location-within-webview)

Minimal geolocation webpage:
(How to get this to display in Android Webview?)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Webview Test</title>

</head>
<body>

<div id='output'></div>

<script>

function success(pos) {

  var latitude = pos.coords.latitude;
  var longitude = pos.coords.longitude;

  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = `Your current position is:  Latitude : ${latitude} Longitude: ${longitude}`;
}

function error(err) {
  console.warn('ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}');
}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stackoverflow.com! Please make your question a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example [M.C.V E](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also check [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to make your post answerable.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class JavaScriptReceiver.java

```
public class JavaScriptReceiver
{
Context mContext;
/** Instantiate the receiver and set the context*/
JavaScriptReceiver(Context c) {
mContext = c;
}
@JavascriptInterface
public void showShopping(){
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ShoppingActivity.class);
mContext.startActivity(intent);
}
@JavascriptInterface
public void showOrders(int orderid){
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MyOrdersActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("order",orderid);
mContext.startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

Then call `addjavascriptinterface()` interface through object of `WebView`.

```
JavaScriptReceiver javaScriptReceiver;
javaScriptReceiver = new JavaScriptReceiver(this);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(javaScriptReceiver, "JSReceiver");
```